# Difficulty configuring SMTP server for sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I would like to send email from my own server, rather than gmail, and I am having a hard time configuring the environments file.

I am able to send email from my development computer when I use gmail credentials

```rb
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  host = 'mysite.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host, protocol: 'http' }
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = host

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { 
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'example.com',
    user_name:            ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password:             ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true }
```

This works fine. But if I try to change the settings from my server, I can't connect.

```rb
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { 
    address:              'mail.mysite.com',
    port:                 465,
    user_name:            ENV["MYSITE_USERNAME"],
    password:             ENV["MYSITE_PASSWORD"],
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true }
```

```
The configuration for the emails on my server are:

-------------------------
Secure SSL/TLS Settings (Recommended)
Username: test@mysite.com
Password: Use the email account’s password.
Incoming Server: mail.mysite.com
IMAP Port: 993 POP3 Port: 995
Outgoing Server: mail.mysite.com
SMTP Port: 465
IMAP, POP3, and SMTP require authentication.
-------------------------
```

I can connect to the serve via Thunderbird using the above setting, but I can't connect with Rails. 
I am using the right username and password.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `smtp_settings` address must be from an email client such as Sendgrid or others. You are currently specifying your own domain (`mysite.com`). They should provide the necessary credentials for you to be able to send an email.

Comment: I have: they are included above. I'm thinking that it has something to do with port 465 requiring SSL, and I don't have that set up in development.

Comment: Of course, you cannot use 3rd party services without `https`. If any 3rd party service accepts such a request, I would seriously reconsider using such a service.

Comment: Here is a sendgrid example: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/rubyonrails/

Answer (score 0):

You need a service to delivery yours emails, i recommend you to use sendgrid, its very simple to configure and up to 2000 emails per month is free. And doesn't set the username and password in your environment variable, set in credentials file.

```rb
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => 'your_sendgrid_username',
  :password => 'your_sendgrid_password',
  :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```